# yaml-cpp format maps with whitespaces

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Using the yaml-cpp library, is it possible to format YAML::Emitter with whitespaces? For example if I have a structure that emits something like this:

```
    Fruit:
     - {Name: Apple, Number: 32}
     - {Name: Oranges, Number: 64}
     - {Name: Pineapple, Number: 128}
```

Can I output something like this:

```
    Fruit:
     - {Name: Apple,      Number: 32}
     - {Name: Oranges,    Number: 64}
     - {Name: Pineapple,  Number: 128}
```

The motivation for this is that I have really large maps that would be easier to read if there was a way to format them so keys lined up column-wise. And the reason I'm using YAML::Flow instead of YAML::Block for the map format is because with the block formatting the file becomes long and tough to read. Any thoughts on how to achieve this or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that; it's not a feature of yaml-cpp. You'll have to decide between block and flow formatting.